# How to create a protected route after login in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new in react. I'm trying to create a project where users would have to login to access a page and I want to protect one route that should be accessible only after succesful login. I don't want fancy user management or anything like that so please don't recommend context or redux. I just want my localhost:3000/editor to be accessible only after login and if someone tries to access /editor without login then they are redirected to login page. so something like isAuthenicated: true/false would be fine in my case I believe but I'm not sure how to pass that in my webapp. I would highly if someone can show me how to do that?
I created this but many errors

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./login";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard";
function App() {
 const [loggedIN, setLoggedIN]=useState(false);
  let privateRoutes = null;
   if(loggedIN){
      privateRoutes =(
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      )}  
  return (
  <>  

  <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navheader">
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/Login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <br />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          {privateRoutes}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </>);
}
export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./loginForm.css";
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
  }
  onchange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  performLogin = async () => {
    var body = {
      password: this.state.password,
      email: this.state.email
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      if (text === "redirect") {
        this.props.setState({loggedIN: true})
        this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
        window.alert("login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="loginForm">
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <TextField
              hintText="Enter your Email"
              floatingLabelText="Email"

              onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({ email: newValue })}
            />

            <br />
            <TextField
              type="password"
              hintText="Enter your password"
              floatingLabelText="password"

              onChange={(event, newValue) =>
                this.setState({ password: newValue })
              }
            />

            <br />
            <RaisedButton
              label="Submit"
              primary={true}
              style={style}
              onClick={event => this.performLogin(event)}
            />

          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15
};
export default Login;
```

editor page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
logout=()=>{
  this.setState({loggedIN: false)}
}  
render() {
    return (
         <div>hello</div>;
        <button onCLick={logout}>Logout</button>  
        )
   }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

edit: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shirley-nn235)

Comment: Try to include a working code sandbox link and format your code more properly, that will help you in order to get an answer.

Comment: addded codesandbox @Christiaan

Answer (score 1):

After successfully logged in, maybe you will get token for authorization purpose.
so after successfully logged in you can store the auth token in cookies.

```
install - npm i universal-cookie --save
```

login.js

```
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./loginForm.css";
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
  }
  onchange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  performLogin = async () => {
    var body = {
      password: this.state.password,
      email: this.state.email
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      // here you will get auth token in response
      // set token in cookie like cookie.set('token', response.token);
      cookies.set('loggedin', true);

      if (text === "redirect") {
        this.props.setState({loggedIN: true})
        this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
        window.alert("login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="loginForm">
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <TextField
              hintText="Enter your Email"
              floatingLabelText="Email"

              onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({ email: newValue })}
            />

            <br />
            <TextField
              type="password"
              hintText="Enter your password"
              floatingLabelText="password"

              onChange={(event, newValue) =>
                this.setState({ password: newValue })
              }
            />

            <br />
            <RaisedButton
              label="Submit"
              primary={true}
              style={style}
              onClick={event => this.performLogin(event)}
            />

          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15
};
export default Login;
```

After that in the dashboard component check for the loggedin boolean in a cookie if it exists then its logged in and authenticated. eg.

dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();


class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
logout=()=>{
  this.setState({loggedIN: false)}
  cookies.set('loggedin', false);
}  
render() {
    // notice here
    if (!cookies.get('loggedin')) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/login'}/>)
        }

    return (
         <div>hello</div>;
        <button onCLick={logout}>Logout</button>  
        )
   }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: just talked to the backend guy, he said, it doesn't send any auth token

Comment: then how you identify its logged in and authenticated user

Comment: what kind of security you are providing for a user then?

Comment: there is an api for logging in. if the user logs in succesfully, then a response "redirect" is sent and if it is "redirect" in response then it sends me to whatever page I want. Now I want to navigate to dashboard page but need that to be protected

Comment: what do you mean by protected ? do you mean nobody can access it if he/she is not logged in?

Comment: yeah exactly. I don't want anybody to be able to access without logging in

Comment: instead of storing token in cookies you can store some flag value to true and redirect if that token is not present or it's false. anyway this is not the best solution for proper authentication

Comment: yeah that's what I wanted, some flag value to redirect. can you show it to me?

Comment: the route is still not protected. someone would still be able to go to dashboard if they do  localhost:3000/dashboard i think??

Comment: yeah but it will redirect back to login page

Answer (score 1):

I think you have error here or it is better to change it

```
let privateRoutes = null;
   if(loggedIN){
      privateRoutes =(
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      )}
```

change it to

```
let privateRoutes =()=>{
    if(loggedIN){
      return(
               <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            )
     }
}
```

but you don't need this!
you could use **render route**

```
<Route path="/home" render={() => {
      if(loggedIN){
      return(<Dashboard ...props/>)
     }else{
             return(<Login ...props/>)
          }
 }} />
```

note that after login ((loggedIN)) will be  true in App.js and it will go to Dashboard automatically

ref:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: check this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: The user not logged trying to access a auth route should be redirected to a not found page or a login page..

Comment: how would I set loggedIN to true in login.js cause that will be props in login.js?!

Comment: you must figure out your fundamental states in your app and write them and their actuator functions like Login in app.js then pass it to auth component then in the component you can send ajax to server to get user info or login error. if login was true you should save user info in user state and make loggedIN true. for writing state actuator functions you should use arrow function or normal function with bind(this) in constructor and pass its name to child component as props so you can call that, in right situation

Comment: just write a function that make LoggedIN true and call it when server send a 200 response (success)

Answer (score 0):

here you have Big Bugs:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
// logout function should not be here it should write in app.js and pass to
// this component with props and just call here if needed
 // and you should use this.logout = () ...
logout=()=>{
  //                      and here
  this.setState({loggedIN: false**)**}
}  
render() {
// here!!! jsx element should wrapped with an element
    return (
        // <div>
         <div>hello</div>;
        <button onCLick={logout}>Logout</button>  
      //</div>
        )
   }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to split routes and manage redirect with an HOC like [redux-auth-wrapper][2]

*App.js*

```
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools'
import LogMonitor from 'redux-devtools-log-monitor'
import DockMonitor from 'redux-devtools-dock-monitor'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import * as reducers from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, reducers, {}))

const DevTools = createDevTools(
  <DockMonitor toggleVisibilityKey="ctrl-h"
               changePositionKey="ctrl-q">
    <LogMonitor theme="tomorrow" />
  </DockMonitor>
)

const enhancer = compose(
  // Middleware you want to use in development:
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
  DevTools.instrument()
)

// Note: passing enhancer as the last argument requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <App />
      {/* <DevTools /> */}
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('mount')
)
```

*auth.js*

```
import locationHelperBuilder from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/locationHelper'
import { connectedRouterRedirect } from 'redux-auth-wrapper/history4/redirect'
import connectedAuthWrapper from 'redux-auth-wrapper/connectedAuthWrapper'

import Loading from './components/Loading'

const locationHelper = locationHelperBuilder({})

const userIsAuthenticatedDefaults = {
  authenticatedSelector: state => state.user.data !== null,
  authenticatingSelector: state => state.user.isLoading,
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsAuthenticated'
}

export const userIsAuthenticated = connectedAuthWrapper(userIsAuthenticatedDefaults)

export const userIsAuthenticatedRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  ...userIsAuthenticatedDefaults,
  AuthenticatingComponent: Loading,
  redirectPath: '/login'
})

export const userIsAdminRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  redirectPath: '/',
  allowRedirectBack: false,
  authenticatedSelector: state => state.user.data !== null && state.user.data.isAdmin,
  predicate: user => user.isAdmin,
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsAdmin'
})

const userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults = {
  // Want to redirect the user when they are done loading and authenticated
  authenticatedSelector: state => state.user.data === null && state.user.isLoading === false,
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsNotAuthenticated'
}

export const userIsNotAuthenticated = connectedAuthWrapper(userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults)

export const userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir = connectedRouterRedirect({
  ...userIsNotAuthenticatedDefaults,
  redirectPath: (state, ownProps) => locationHelper.getRedirectQueryParam(ownProps) || '/protected',
  allowRedirectBack: false
})
```

[Working example](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper/tree/master/examples/react-router-4) based on **React Router v4**

**What I do**

in main routing (usualli App.js):

```
import { userIsAuthenticated, userIsNotAuthenticated } from './auth';
// ...code
const isNotAuth = userIsNotAuthenticated(Login);
const isAuth = userIsAuthenticated(AuthRoutes);
// ...code
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/login" component={isNotAuth} /> // Notice the *exact* path
  <Route path="/" component={isAuth} /> // Notice the *not exact path*
  <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

*AuthRoutes.js*

Those routes will be provided only if the user is authenticated

```
// ...code

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/homepage" component={HomePage} />
  // ...other routes
</Switch>
```

[2] https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper

Comment: will adding these two pages be enough? what else would I have to change in my code after adding these two pages in my codesandbox? could you please show me as I'm stuck and can't find a way to implement it

Comment: although the doc are enough, I've provided a nice startpoint with another example